# Areas of a rectangle, congruent squares, inscribed in a circle. Ratio of areas with different congruent squares.

Tags: geometry

**(a)** Shows a semicircle of radius 1 with an inscribed Rectangle $R_2$, formed from two adjacent congruent squares:

[image]

**Show the area of $R_2$ is 1.**

Using Pythagoras theorem for △ ABC:

$1^2 = x^2 + x^2 => 1 = 2x^2 => x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$

Area of $R_2 = 2x^2 = 2 * (\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}})^2$

=> Area of $R_2 = 1$ (QED)

**(b)** Shows a semicircle of radius 1 with an inscribed square $R_1$

[image]

**Area of $R_1$:**

As above using Pythagoras theorem for △ ABC:

$1^2 = x^2 + (\frac{x}{2})^2 => 1 = \frac{5}{4}x^2 => x = \sqrt{\frac{4}{5}}$

Area of $R_1 = x^2 = (\sqrt{\frac{4}{5}})^2$

=> Area of $R_1 = \frac{4}{5}$

**(c)** Figures also show semicircle of radius 1 with inscribed rectangles $R_3$ and $R_5$, formed from 3 and 5 adjacent congruent squares respectively. Find the ratio of the areas of $R_3:R_5$ leaving your answer in the form *m*:*n*, in lowest form for integers *m* and *n*.

[image]
[image]

Using Pythagoras theorem as previously yields:

Area $R_3 = \frac{12}{13}$ and Area $R_5 = \frac{20}{29}$

Least common multiple of 13 and 29, 377 gives:

Area $R_3 = \frac{41}{377}$ and Area $R_5 = \frac{33}{377}$
$=> m:n = 41:33$

Does that seem reasonable, is there a more succinct, elegant, solution,
for example based on information from questions (a) and (b)?

Comment: I doubt so.  In general, $R_n=\frac{4n}{4+n^2}$, hence the ratio $\frac{R_n}{R_m}=\frac{m}{n}\frac{4+m^2}{4+n^2}$.  I see no slick way to represent the latter fraction in lowest numbers.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHoppe, the general equation is something I wasn't able to see, and hence went through the entire Pythagoras theorem calculation for $R_3$ and $R_5$. I think the way the 3 parts of the question are structured suggests you should be spotting a general pattern, and applying in (c) to quickly determine the areas and hence ratio. That in itself makes it more succinct and elegant.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe How did you come up with the general equation $R_n=\frac{4n}{4+n^2}$, is there a methodology i can try to apply, or a case of deduction through experience?

Comment: Let $a$ be the height of the ractangle, then $n\cdot a$ is its lengths.  From Pythagoras we get $(na/2)^2+a^2=1^2$, that is $a^2=\frac{4}{4+n^2}$.  From here the area is $na\cdot a=\frac{4n}{4+n^2}$.

Comment: It is straight forward geometrical - rotate triangles along the diagonals and create a square.